# Resize the height of dropdown for Year in jquery-UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the Jquery UI datepicker component(jquery-ui-1.12.1). But I am unable to modify the size of year dropdown. I want to fix the height of dropdown(specially for 'year'), as it is showing a long list, which overflow the window boundary, in case of Mozila Firefox. Here's the picture:

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: I will double check, yet I think you need to define the number of option items to be shown by `<select>` via CSS.

Comment: Sorry, not CSS, it's in HTML as the `size` attribute. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Please provide an example and we can assist further.

Answer (score 0):

The Options List for `<select>` is rendered by the browser and it's `overflow` and `height` cannot be easily managed. I have a work-around, using jQuery UI SelectMenu. See here:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
  $("#datepicker").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".ui-datepicker-month, .ui-datepicker-year").selectmenu();
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

```css
span.ui-selectmenu-button.ui-button {
  width: 30%;
}

ul.ui-menu {
  max-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

This replaces the `<select>` element with a manageable dropdown list. Since it's based on the box model, you can over ride the CSS and style it yourself.